# Adding days to specific day

Tags: php, strtotime

Many examples are about adding days to this day. But how to do it, if I have different starding day?

For example (Does not work):

```
$day='2010-01-23';

// add 7 days to the date above
$NewDate= Date('$day', strtotime("+7 days"));
echo $NewDate;
```

Example above does not work. How should I change the starding day by putting something else in the place of Date?

Comment: is '$day' a typo?  you don't wrap variables in quotes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For a very basic fix based on your code:

```
$day='2010-01-23';

// add 7 days to the date above
$NewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . " +7 days"));
echo $NewDate;
```

If you are using PHP 5.3+, you can use the new DateTime libs which are very handy:

```
$day = '2010-01-23';

// add 7 days to the date above
$NewDate = new DateTime($day);
$NewDate->add(new DateInterval('P7D');
echo $NewDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

I've fully switched to using `DateTime` myself now as it's very powerful. You can also specify the timezone easily when instantiating, i.e. `new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'))`. You can use the methods `add()` and `sub()` for changing the date with DateInterval objects. Here's documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: $NewDate->add(new DateInterval('P7D'); - you need to add an extra ')' at the end here :)

Answer (score 16):

```
$NewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($day)));
```

Answer (score 2):

From php.com binupillai2003

```
<?php
/*
Add day/week/month to a particular date
@param1 yyyy-mm-dd
@param1 integer
by Binu V Pillai on 2009-12-17
*/

function addDate($date,$day)//add days
{
$sum = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$date")) . " +$day days");
$dateTo=date('Y-m-d',$sum);
return $dateTo;
}

?>
```

Comment: While "$date" may technically work, it's poor syntax, just say $date