# Add days to date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

```
$userPromotionDays = $user->premiumDate; // 2019.08.28
$daysToAdd = 5
```

How can I add $userPromotionDays to $daysToAdd (in Laravel/Carbon)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing dates with Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048657/incrementing-dates-with-carbon)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create date with custom format and then add days to it using carbon.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', $user->premiumDate);
$daysToAdd = 5;
$date = $date->addDays($daysToAdd);
dd($date);
```

You can see details documentation [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub).

Answer (score 6):

Laravel uses the package called `Carbon` by nesbot.com, and this is how you add days:

```
$user->premiumDate->addDays(5);
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

This will only work if you have casted the field `premiumDate` as a date field in the model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 5):

You can add dates to your date like this, if your date is carbon instance:

```
$userPromotionDays->addDays($daysToAdd);
```

If your date isn't instance of Carbon, initiate it:

```
$userPromotionDays = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', $user->premiumDate);
$userPromotionDays->addDays($daysToAdd);
```

Not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+ '.daysToAdd , strtotime($userPromotionDays)));
```

check this link
[Adding days to specific day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923832/adding-days-to-specific-day)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - as far as I see, it does not make use of `$daysToAdd`, and it does not use any Carbon features

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addDays()` method of `Carbon`. First create a `Carbon` date object with `createFromFormat` and then add days.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', $user->premiumDate)->addDays($daysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without Carbon**

*For full example go to - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php*

below code is for only add days

> $d->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$fineStamp = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s').substr(microtime(), 1, 9);
$d = new DateTime($fineStamp);
$d->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
$date=$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u').PHP_EOL;
return substr($date, 0, -2);
```